# Azure resource group - How can I tell which ones are "related"?

Tags: azure

Recently I was provisioning a new Azure Synapse resource, which ended up creating 2 different resource groups.

I understand a resource group is basically a container for related items, fair enough but thinking about it more I am actually confused why would Azure decide to create two separate resource groups instead of just putting it all into one?

The bigger burning question I have is after creating a number of resources - Lets say each one spawns multiple resource groups.

How can I tell which resource group is a "child" or a "parent" of another?

Comment: Resource Groups are independent - there are no parent/child relationships. I suggest looking at what was placed in each Resource Group. Aside from that: probably better to ask on ServerFault, since this isn't programming-related but more infrastructure-related.

Comment: This question is a bad fit because you're not going to get an explanation from the person who made the decision to implement Synapse resource groups that way -- the answer is "because they thought it was a good idea". Generally, you will only get a resource creating an additional resource group when that resource is creating multiple self-managed additional resources. It's not worth worrying about. If you have a specific **reason** why you're concerned about it, ask a question about your concern and you may get a response that provides you with strategies to address it.

Comment: @DavidMakogon - Thanks for the tip! I didnt know about ServerFault and will try there.

Comment: @DanielMann - When I was provisioning Azure Synapse I sort of just went through the set up quickly (just learning about it), and this was the first time I noticed that it spawned 2 resource groups. When I deleted the "main one" it seemed to delete the secondary one as well, which implied to me that theres some sort of relationship. I guess my question came out of concern on how best to manage resources with multiple resource groups that have automatic names given to them. As I had a number of other resource groups, I couldnt even tell the second one was related. Thank you for the advice

Comment: For anyone that comes across this thread in the future I actually finally found this Azure article: [ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/overview#managed-resource-group ] It sort of explains what is a "Managed application" and how it can at times create a "managed resource group". The managed resource group can be specifically named at time of creating the managed application, so I just thought its good to be aware that this extra resource group is created and to document it appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@rodneyc8063** Thanks for updating the concern of your question. Posting your discussion in the comments as an Answer to help other community members.

As said by **Daniel Mann** you are getting the additional resource group because your synapse workspace is creating the **managed resource group**.

A managed resource group is like a container which can hold the resources required by your resource. It is created **by default** when your workspace is created.
You can name it if you want, else its name will be created automatically.

[image]

- When you delete the Main Resource Group of your resource, then the resources inside it also will be deleted.
- The managed resource group also deleted when you delete the resource(managed application).
- That’s why the **second resource group is deleted** when you delete the first one.
- As far as I know apart from this there is no relationship between them.

**References:**

[Overview of managed applications - Azure Managed Applications | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/overview#managed-resource-group)

[Blog from DataSimAntics about managed resource group](https://datasimantics.com/2022/01/31/managed-resource-groups/#:%7E:text=Managed%20resource%20group%20is%20a,when%20your%20workspace%20is%20created.).

Comment: Thanks for the further clarification! This is exactly what I wanted to confirm. Initially when I saw the multiple resource groups it concerned me a bit in terms of how to document/manage the resources properly. Its good to be aware that this extra resource group is created, as when I first saw it I was like what the heck!